# Filling the area below a Bezier curve

Tags: tikz-pgf, xetex

I use the following code in order to fill with color the area between a function and the x axis and it works properly.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.2]
\foreach \x in {1.000,1.001,...,4.500}   
\draw[purple!15!white] (\x,{0})--(\x, {0.5*cos(deg(0.5*pi*\x)+0.5*pi)+2});
\draw[very thick, ->] (-1,0) -- (6,0)node[pos=1,below]{$x$};
\draw[very thick, ->] (0,-1) -- (0,4)node[pos=1,left]{$y$};
\node[below left](o) at (0,0){$0$};
\draw[ultra thick,purple,smooth,domain=0.5:5,samples=257,]
plot (\x, {0.5*cos(deg(0.5*pi*\x)+0.5*pi)+2});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How can I do the same, using a Bezier curve (e.g. \draw[ultra thick, purple,smooth] (0.5,1.5)..controls(2,-0.5) and (3.5,4.5)..(5,2.5);)
instead of 0.5*cos(deg(0.5*pi*\x)+0.5*pi)+2 ?

Comment: Filling an area under a curve that way is already a last-resort solution. PGF/TikZ would already provide a `\clip`ping solution for that. The PGFPlots package provides the [tag:fillbetween] library and if that doesn't work we can always use `spath3`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Filling an area with roughly 3500 thin stripes is something I'd do as a last resort. Just without delving into PGFPlots' [`fillbetween` library](https://tikz.dev/pgfplots/libs-fillbetween) (see [fillbetween](/questions/tagged/fillbetween)) and the whole power of the [`spath3` library](https://ctan.org/pkg/spath3) we can do this by using an appropriate `\clip`.

The `current subpath start` is a dynamic coordinate that references the start of the current subpath – thanks Caption Obvious – which is the point where the last [move to operation](https://tikz.dev/tikz-paths#sec-14.1) landed. That's where `cycle` would bring us to.

However we don't want to cycle directly to that point but want enclose everything below it up to the *y* = 0.
The coordinate `(0,0 -| current subpath start)` is the base point of `current subpath start`.

### Code

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  scale=1.2,
  declare function={
    trig(\x)=.5*cos(deg(.5*pi*\x)+.5*pi)+2;
  }]
\fill[purple!15] plot[smooth, domain=1:4.5, samples=257] (\x, trig \x)
                 |- (0,0-|current subpath start) -- cycle;

\draw[very thick, ->] (-1,0) -- (6,0)node[below]{$x$};
\draw[very thick, ->] (0,-1) -- (0,4)node[left] {$y$};
\node[below left] {$0$};
\draw[ultra thick, purple, smooth, domain=0.5:5, samples=257]
  plot (\x, trig \x);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  scale=1.2,
  my curve/.style={
    insert path={(0.5,1.5)..controls(2,-0.5) and (3.5,4.5)..(5,2.5)}}
]
\begin{scope}
  \clip (1,0) rectangle (4.5, 4); % the y value of 4 needs to be carefully chosen
  \fill[purple!15, my curve] |- (0,0-|current subpath start) -- cycle;
\end{scope}
\draw[very thick, ->] (-1,0) -- (6,0) node[below]{$x$};
\draw[very thick, ->] (0,-1) -- (0,4) node[left] {$y$};
\node[below left] {$0$};
\draw[ultra thick, purple, my curve];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.2]
        \begin{scope}
            \clip (0.5,0) -- (0.5,1.5) ..controls (2,-0.5) and (3.5,4.5).. (5,2.5) |- cycle;
            \foreach \x in {1.000,1.001,...,4.500}   
                \draw[purple!15!white] (\x,{0}) -- ++(0,4);
        \end{scope}
        \draw[very thick, ->] (-1,0) -- (6,0)node[pos=1,below]{$x$};
        \draw[very thick, ->] (0,-1) -- (0,4)node[pos=1,left]{$y$};
        \node[below left] (o) at (0,0){$0$};
        \draw[ultra thick, purple, smooth]
            (0.5,1.5) ..controls (2,-0.5) and (3.5,4.5).. (5,2.5);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

As `plot` is usable into a path, here is a simple solution:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.2]
  \fill[purple!15!white](1,0) 
  -- plot[smooth,domain=1:4.5,samples=257](\x,{0.5*cos(deg(0.5*pi*\x)+0.5*pi)+2})
  -- (4.5,0) -- cycle;
  \draw[very thick, ->] (-1,0) -- (6,0)node[pos=1,below]{$x$};
  \draw[very thick, ->] (0,-1) -- (0,4)node[pos=1,left]{$y$};
  \node[below left](o) at (0,0){$0$};
  \draw[ultra thick,purple,smooth,domain=0.5:5,samples=257,]
  plot (\x, {0.5*cos(deg(0.5*pi*\x)+0.5*pi)+2});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The same method used between two plots (using `declare function` for readability):

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.2]
  \tikzset{
    declare function={
      f1(\x) = 0.5*cos(deg(0.5*pi*\x)+0.5*pi)+1;
      f2(\x) = 0.5*cos(deg(2*pi*\x)+0.5*pi)+3;
    },
    samples=256,
  }
  \fill[purple!15!white] plot[smooth,domain=1:4.5](\x,{f1(\x)})
                     -- (4.5,0) -- (1,0) -- cycle;
  \fill[cyan!15!white] plot[smooth,domain=1.5:4](\x,{f1(\x)})
                   --  plot[smooth,domain=4:1.5](\x,{f2(\x)}) -- cycle;
  \draw[very thick, ->] (-1,0) -- (6,0)node[pos=1,below]{$x$};
  \draw[very thick, ->] (0,-1) -- (0,4)node[pos=1,left]{$y$};
  \node[below left](o) at (0,0){$0$};
  \draw[ultra thick,purple] plot[smooth,domain=0.5:5] (\x,{f1(\x)});
  \draw[ultra thick,cyan]   plot[smooth,domain=0.5:5] (\x,{f2(\x)});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice. Out of curiosity, why `samples=257`?

Comment: @Alan I just used the number of samples indicated in the question...

Comment: @PaulGaborit Useful answer. Do you know if I there is a way to do something like that with two plot functions and the area between them?

Comment: @GSpyros Done...